# Auto Keyframe stuck 2.83

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation

Today I was simply trying to do some rendering of smoke/particles. I ran into an issue however. The smoke doesn't actively move as expected. I realized the smoke effect was being keyframed (without auto keyframe being enabled) and tried creating a new object. Sure enough it would remember whatever movements my first pass had but after that it fails to update correctly. At first I thought it was possibly just a bug with the "industry standard" version so I jumped over the the "normal" version after a clean uninstall/re-install. Nope same issue. I tried diving into forums and unfortunately found no good solutions. Best I could find is to "turn off auto key" but again it isn't on in the first place. I can upload a video showing the issue as well.

Computer specs:

- Windows 10
- i9 processor
- 2080ti graphics
- Asus mobo

Again this is base version downloaded straight from the website today (6/15/2020).

Comment: Which properties are keyframed?

Comment: It seems the smoke animation is what is keyframed. When I get off of work tonight I will upload footage

Comment: Alright just did a quick screen- cap of the issue. Link below. 

https://youtu.be/NAMm4oWjuC4

As you can see even with a fresh object using the quick smoke effect it just gets stuck. If you need screenshots of any settings just let me know.

Comment: All I saw in the video was: Once you reach the end of the timeline, what's in the cache is considered baked. So if it starts over, it reads from the cache, rather than resimulating. So back to my question: which properties are keyframed?

Comment: Ah. Maybe I am misunderstanding. So I am wanting it to re-simulate everytime. Is there a setting I can change to make this happen? Thank you in advance!